# Still getting "no layers detected" after repairing model in PrusaSlicer console

Tags: stl, prusaslicer

I tried to slice an stl file using the PrusaSlicer console and I got the `No layers were detected. You might want to repair your STL file(s) or check their size or thickness and retry.` message. I tried repairing the model with 3 different services and I still get the same error. When I load the fixed stl file into the PrusaSlicer gui, it doesn't say that the model is broken. How can the console and gui give 2 different results and how can I fix this?

Here's an image of the model being loaded into the gui version. It states that the model is broken but was automatically fixed.
[image: broken model]
Then I manually fixed the model using Netfabb and the model is no longer broken according to the gui version.
[image: fixed model]
Yet when I try to slice the repaired model using the console, it fails again.
[image: error message]

PrusaSlicer version is 2.3.0 on Windows 10.
You can find the stl and repaired stl [here](http://sendanywhe.re/I78RT83D).

Comment: Cura says, those files are perfectly fine..

Comment: Yes I know that the files are fine, I don't get why the console slicer is still producing that error.

Comment: degenerate faces are faces that do have no surface area... maybe internal geometry?

Answer (score 2):

Still don't have an actual answer as to why repairing the stl file didn't seem to work, but since my stl file was a combination of different stl files I tried repairing the individual stl files before combining them, which resolved the problem.

Comment: Are you printing multiple parts? Try selecting all, merge then slice.

Comment: commenting to confirm that Selecting all then merging made it work to slice my stuff. I was adding generic cylinder to make a small ad-hoc support on my model